# Append Line Bash File

Tags: bash, sed

One liner in bash (for example using `sed`) to append a line before the last line in a file.

Example

Old File

```
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
```

New file

```
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
--new foo bar
foo bar
```

I tried `sed` on OSX like that

```
sed '$ i --new foo bar' file.sh
```

I get this error `command i expects \ followed by text`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some versions of sed (e.g. GNU sed) support the `i` command on the same line as the text to be inserted, the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/sed.html) specifies the usage like this:

```
sed '$i\
--new foo bar' file.sh
```

That is, the `i` is followed by a backslash and a newline, then the text to be inserted.

Comment: so this works as expected :) but I have to add line break after the inserted one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Backslash and newline or new `-e` expression is missing after `i`:

```
sed -e '$i\' -e '--new foo bar'
```

Comment: @OdinRW: It depends on your version and flavour of sed.